# Does an ATMEGA328P need a crystal oscillator while using ISP?

Tags: arduino

I tried to burn the Arduino bootloader to an ATMEGA328P on my custom PCB but it failed. I want to know if it is possible that my crystal might be broken and causing problems.

While using ISP it seems like SPI uses the clock signal from the master (programmer) so the target MCU has no need for the crystal to do ISP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPI clock from the master are used only for SPI clock. MCU itself has still to be clocked on the main source as in usual working condition, which drives the Fcpu. Moreover SPI clock frequency has to be at least two times less than the main clock.

If your MCU fuses are set to use external crystal, you have to install it. Same way you do for normal operating condition. Default fuse settings runs MCU from internal RC osc, which makes it possible to program it without external crystal osc. But if you've changed this to external osc/clock, you have to provide it even in programming mode.

This assumes you use SPI (serial, normal voltage) programming mode (>99% of usual programming routines). HVPP (High voltage parallel programming) mode doesn't "suffers" from such issues.

Comment: Then how I set fuse bit at the first place?

Comment: @Mlab what do you mean? If you have new MCU it's set to be clocked from internal RC. You can program it without external crystal. That includes fuses too. Once you program fuses to run from external crystal next time you have to connect correct crystal (and caps) to appropriate pins.

Comment: What should I do if I want to burn boot loader to new chip? do I need to set fusebit first?

Comment: @Mlab It doesn't really matters (as long as you don't disabling RESET or SPI programming via fuses) but usually program memory (flash, i.e. your bootloader) are programmed before burning fuses.